# Make my clone draggable

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable

This is my test code for cloning from right to left.
Eventually I want to drag my clones into the `leftDiv` and no go further.
Anyone have any ideas? Be free to test it. Thanks!

```js
    var uniqueId = 1;
    $(function() {
         $('.clonebutton').click(function() {
             var copy = $("#cloneableDiv").clone(true);
             var formId = 'text' + uniqueId;
             copy.attr('id', formId );
             
               
             $('#leftDiv').append(copy.addClass("TextField"));
             $('#' + formId).find('input,select').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + uniqueId); 
                 
             });
             uniqueId++;  
         });
    });
```

```css
    #leftDiv {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     border:2px solid black;
     width: 50%;
     height: 600px;
    }
    #rightDiv {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     border:2px solid black;
     width: 50%;
     height: 600px;
    }
    #cloneableDiv {
     border:2px solid black;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     margin: 10px;
     border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #clonebutton {
     position: absolute;
     top: 10px;
     right: 10px;
    }
    .TextField {
     border:2px solid red;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     margin: 10px;
     border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leftDiv">
     
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv">
    <input type="button" name="clonebutton" id="clonebutton" class="clonebutton" value="clone">
     <div id="cloneableDiv">test</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to clone it, and then drag the box saying 'text' inside the left div? Or drag from the right div to left, cloning it in the process?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
after the text is cloned, then it has to be draggable around in the left div!
and, when i spam clone, it will eventually go outside the leftDiv, i dont know how to prevent that either